# Hardware requirements for one instance Geoserver/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, hardware

What hardware minimun requirements do you recomend for one instance of geoserver and postgis and 20 concurrent users?
Vectorial data stored in PostGIS is around 20 MB only. 
I need the ammount of RAM, disk space, bandwith, server cores and processor velocity.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on a lot of things. But if all your data is 20 mb you shouldn't need very much of anything.

Maybe java and geoserver will need some ram to feel good. But PostGIS shouldn't need any more than the OS needs for such a job.

So if you run some Linux distro I don't think you will find a computer that can't handle that load.

Maybe 1 GB of RAM is recommended and any decent 5 year old cpu. 
For disc you will need maybe 7 GB to have some extra space for future updates.

How fast your users will experience your maps depends more on how you build things than the hardware.

Will you serve in some vector format or as wms-service or what.
Will you cache the output?
and so on....

Comment: 1GB off RAM is not enough but 2 should be

Comment: @user30184 Well, if you cache the output so the server only serves static data I gyess 1 GB will give quite decent performance. And to render and cache 20 mb of data in all zoom levels shouldn't be that heavy, should it? But maybe geoserver is demanding, that I don't know so well.

Comment: From my experience it is necessary to give 1 GB for the jre to run GeoServer and GWC smoothly and operating system and PostGIS needs a few hundred MB more. It is not so much about performance, it is more about making it work at all. If jre must start to swap data to the disk then everything is pretty slow.

Comment: I would say 2 GB also, Java being such a memory beast, but frankly it would be hard to find a machine with a spec low enough that the above requirement would cause a problem. All on one machine, though, that is where the problems will begin :D

Comment: Great, then I understand. GeoServer and Java is the bottleneck. But as you say it shouldn't be any problem.